# Collect traffic from mobile app to IoT device

Tags: wifi, proxy, iot

I have a mobile app that connects to a IoT device over port 8888 to send commands. I'm not sure how to intercept this. MITMproxy was not able to capture the data as the app would not load behind a proxy. I own the devices and a router to try capture this data.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running your mobile app in the Android emulator from the Android SDK? I think, you should be able to capture the traffic between the app and IoT using Wireshark on the same PC.

Comment: The app is able to recognize that It's in a proxy. I was hoping to be able to capture the WI-FI data and decrypt that.

Comment: I see, and just to be sure, did you try using WireShark? May be this might be helpful
https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/48500/wireless-traffic-tofrom-another-device-is-not-getting-captured/

Comment: Thank you @Rajiv however just capturing the data is not enough as it uses SSL, I belive it's TLS1.2 hence the proxy.